# I am trying to create one randomly selected individual to be positive in a random distribution, but my code is incorrect

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create one randomly selected individual in a random distribution to be infected with a disease. Firstly I created a random distribution using:

```
 xcoord<-sample(1:100,60)
 ycoord<-sample(1:100,60)
 infectionstatus<-rep(0,60)
 df2<-data.frame(xcoord,ycoord,infectionstatus)
```

This gives me a plot looking something like this:
[image]

In order to randomly choose a point and assign it a value of positive, I have tried creating a for loop like so:

```
for(j in 0:60) {
df2[infectionstatus[j]]<-df2[infectionstatus[j]+1]}
```

But this creates an error:

Error in x[[jj]] <- v : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

How can I randomly choose one individual to have an assigned value of 1?

Comment: Why don't you sample a row, like this `df2[sample(1:nrow(df2),3] <- 1`. I don't understand you need a loop here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample one number from 1 to 60 (call it `a`):

```
a<-sample(1:60, 1)
```

And change

```
df2$infectionstatus[a]<-1
```